# Class assignment: race time sorter

Tags: python

Okay, so here is the assignment:

> You're a swimmer, and you want to compare all of your race times to find the >fastest one. Write a program that continuously takes race times as doubles >from standard input, until the input is "no more races," at which point it >should print out the time of your fastest race.

fairly straight forward, or so I thought. With a little work I came up with the following:

```
race_time = input("")
list1=[]
while race_time != ("no more races"):
    list1.append("")
if race_time == ("no more races"):
    print(min(list1))
```

Okay, so ask for input. So long as the input in race_time does not equal "no more races" you enter your next time and that value gets appended to list1. Once race_time equals "no more races" print the minimum value from list1.

Straight forward right?

Well I plunked that code into MyProgrammingLab and submitted it. it gave me the following... 'feedback'

> Your code did not work as expected.
>   More Hints:
>       ⇒     We think you might want to consider using: float
>       ⇒     Solutions with your approach don't usually use: ==
>       ⇒     Solutions with your approach don't usually use: if

Okay... so why should I use those?

Anyway, so I tossed the code into IDLE and ran it. Here I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\F2-233\Desktop\times.py", line 4, in 
>      list1.append("")
>   MemoryError

So... what is a traceback? The book hasn't talked about this and in a search online I'm finding lots of code examples to address the problem, but not finding an explanation of what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the format of a "race time" input? (e.g. is it something like "3.456" seconds)

In any case, here's a code that continuously ask the user for input until "no more races" is given, in which case, the program exits:

```
def race_time():

    list1 = []

    while True:

        race_time = input("")

        if race_time == ("no more races"):

            print("min race time: {0}".format(min(list1)))

            break

        else:

            list1.append(float(race_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, to answer your question about *Traceback*:  A "traceback" is a map to the location in your code that caused it to break during run time.

The reason you're seeing this is because you are exceeding available memory for your application at the line described in the Traceback: `list1.append("")`

In this case, it is important to note that `race_time = input("")` will execute only once (when `race_time` is initialized).  It will not execute every time you reference `race_time`.

While this won't complete your assignment for you, it will point you in a decent direction:

```
race_time = input("")
list1=[]
while race_time != ("no more races"):
    list1.append("")
    race_time = input("") # prompt for another race time
if race_time == ("no more races"):
    print(min(list1))
```

Comment: is it a memory limitation I implemented in the code or is it a system limit?

Comment: Your upper limit depends on your environment => operating system, python runtime (jython, activatestate, pure python, etc), 32bit vs 64bit process, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but I see 2 problems in your solution.

1. The input prompt is outside the loop, this mean that the user will only be asked for the race time only once.
2. The user input is saved as string, to do the value comparison it must be a float (double in python).

The resulting code is:

```
list1 = []

while True:
    race_time = input()
    if race_time == 'no more races':
        break
    list1.append(float(race_time))

print(min(list1))
```

Comment: *sigh* this is one of the reasons I am really loathing MyProgrammingLab. I take that code, drop it into IDLE, works fine. Takes numbers until I say "no more races" then it displays the lowest exactly like it should. I put the code into MPL and I get "I haven't seen a solution yet that uses float". I take float out, resubmit it and I get "You should really consider using float"

My god this is aggravating! But... MPL is what I have to appease for my grades.

Comment: @MichaelCividanes There are tons of ways of solving the same problem with any language.  MyProgrammingLab is likely encouraging you to use specific techniques that they think are best practice.  Don't get discouraged, keep chugging on.